# How do I create a ListView like the YouTube App?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

I've been working on an Android Application, and one of the major issues i've been trying to deal with is customization of a ListView or GridView.

Does anybody know how to make my app with a ListView or GridView to look very much like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWXAZ.jpg)?

Comment: I recommend that you post some code showing what you have done. This is too vague of a question.

Comment: In this community we do not write the code for the other people but we help them solving out problems or we give them advices. So before you ask this questions, YOU HAVE TO WORK ON YOUR OWN CODE.

Comment: I will provide the code soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important thing to apply this kind of design is properly implement adapter, which will represent every piece of data (one video in your situation).

More or less in for situation it will look like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

//you main picture
  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  //layout to place other info like number of likes, comments, author etc.
      <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center">

   //number of likes
          <TextView ... >

   //number of comments
          <TextView ... >

    ...

      </RelativeLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Set those views in positions, which suit you.