# Android ImageView custom shape

Tags: android, imageview

i'm trying to `design a custom shaped imageview` in my application... similar to the one in **Yahoo news digest application**...

Here's the shape i'm seeking to achieve :

[image]

Anyone have any idea how to do this? Thanks guys!

Comment: Maybe you can use mask to shape image ([here you will find some detatils](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/2656)), and please labels based on adapter layout ([I've described it here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25043187/2004186))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you'll simply need an image (filling the background) and overlapping view for displaying the news, date and day. I suggest you look for `RelativeLayout`.